# Insert variables/constants in YAML file

Tags: yaml

Let's say I want to avoid inserting the same value multiple times in a YAML file:

```
- name: region_1
  inputs:
    tag_name: constant_tag_name
    aws_region: us-east-1

- name: region_2
  inputs:
    tag_name: constant_tag_name
    aws_region: us-west-2
...
```

So in the above example, I would like to define a variable somewhere above all sections with the value `constant_tag_name` and mention the variable everywhere the value is the same. If the name is to change, I would want to change it at the top and have it be reflected everywhere. I looked at YAML aliases but they appear to be for a code *section*, whereas here I only have one variable. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an alias, like so:

```
- const_tag: &CT "constant_tag_name"
- name: region_1
  inputs:
    tag_name: *CT
    aws_region: us-east-1
- name: region_2
  inputs:
    tag_name: *CT
    aws_region: us-west-2
```

Try it out here: [yaml-online-parser.appspot.com](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---%0A-%20const_tag%3A%20%26CT%20%22constant_tag_name%22%0A-%20name%3A%20region_1%0A%20%20inputs%3A%0A%20%20%20%20tag_name%3A%20*CT%0A%20%20%20%20aws_region%3A%20us-east-1%0A-%20name%3A%20region_2%0A%20%20inputs%3A%0A%20%20%20%20tag_name%3A%20*CT%0A%20%20%20%20aws_region%3A%20us-west-2%0A&type=json)